# React and Emotion: Specify font size

Tags: css, reactjs, emotion

I am using `emotion` to style and display the equation for compound interest in my React app. My `render()` returns this:

```
<div css ={equation}>
  <p>
  P (1 +</p>
  <p css={fraction}>
    <span className="num">1</span>
    <span className="symbol">/</span>
    <span className="bottom">2</span>
  </p>
  )
   <sup>(nt)</sup>
</div>
```

And outside of my component I have:

```
const fraction = css`
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    letter-spacing: 0.0001em;
    text-align: center;

    .num {
      display: block;
      padding: 0;
      height: 12px;
      line-height: 12px;
    }

    .bottom {
      border-top: thin solid black;
    }

    .symbol {
      display: none;
    }
`
const equation = css`
font-size: 100%;
.p{
    font-size:large !important;
  }
`;
```

The fraction is correctly styled. However, I cannot get the font of the `p` elements to change. The only way I got it to was by switching the `p` to `h1` elements - but I don't want to do that. I want to be able to specify the font size inside my emotion css styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I noticed as an issue in your code.

- You are passing `.p { ...` inside the equation which is not a class selector but should have been an element selector like `p { ...`
- Your react `div` has to use a `className` in order to make that effect applied

Here is the sandbox code changes: https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-xh53z?fontsize=14

Just copying here for your reference:

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { css } from "react-emotion";

const fraction = css`
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
  letter-spacing: 0.0001em;
  text-align: center;
  .num {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 12px;
  }
  .bottom {
    border-top: thin solid black;
  }
  .symbol {
    display: none;
  }
`;

 // Notice the p inside the equation
const equation = css`
  p { 
    font-size: large !important;
  }
`;

// Rather than css={}, you should be using className={}
const App = () => (
  <div className={equation}>
    <p>
      P (1 +
      <p className={fraction}>
        <span className="num">1</span>
        <span className="symbol">/</span>
        <span className="bottom">2</span>
      </p>
      )<sup>(nt)</sup>
    </p>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I also moved the closing `</p>` tag at the last to ensure it's getting applied as per `inline-block`

**Updated 1:**

Here is the latest updated version: https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-1tjc7

As per their latest [blog](https://emotion.sh/docs/migrating-to-emotion-10#codemoddable) you should be using:

```
import styled from '@emotion/styled'
import { css } from 'emotion'
```

instead of `import styled, { css } from 'react-emotion'`

**Update 2:**

In case you cannot use vanilla emotion, then you can consider using the following:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
/** @jsx jsx */
import { css, jsx } from "@emotion/core";
```

According to their [documentation](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#jsx-pragma):

There are 2 ways to get started with the css prop.

- Babel Preset (Can't use in Create-React-App or CodeSandbox)
- JSX Pragma (This involves to just add the above to lines of code)

I have updated the same codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/emotion-0z3vz

Comment: Hmm I cannot recreate this - I don't know if its because I'm using `import { css } from '@emotion/core'` and not `import { css } from "react-emotion";`? Also I get a `<p> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>` warning

Comment: Are you using react? Then you should be able to use `react-emotion` which is from their sandbox  demo example. If you are using just the jsx and it's library then you can use `@emotion/core`

Comment: `@emotion/core` requires React (so I am using react :) ) and `react-emotion` is an old library that my setup doesn't support

Comment: @maddie I referred to their github main README here: https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion which was pointing to https://codesandbox.io/s/pk1qjqpw67 is still using an older version of `emotions` for react. So for your solution, I will update the answer again.

Comment: @maddie I have added a new update with their latest version 10. Which states to use `import styled from '@emotion/styled'` & `import { css } from 'emotion'` instead of  `import styled, { css } from 'react-emotion'`

Comment: eslinter doesn't like "vanilla emotion" - have to use `@emotion/core` not `'emotion'`

Comment: @maddie I have updated the one without vanilla emotions. Their documentation is really bad. It really doesn't convey what they want to tell us!